# PHP cURL - receive return transfer in spite of timeout?

Tags: php, curl, return, timeout

So I'm trying to run a `cURL` session to execute an external PHP script during runtime. I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to receive the external script's output as string, but currently the script seems to be buggy and stuck in a loop somewhere, since `cURL` execution doesn't terminate until the max execution time of PHP runs out.

So I set `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` in hope of receiving some kind of string output anyway for debugging, but even by timeout `cURL` doesn't return any output for that script. And I can't run the external script directly since it would lack vital `POST` variables. Is there some different way to receive the output as string anyway?

Comment: did you write the external script?

Comment: yes I did, I have full control about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your keen to crack on with running the external script via cURL, you're better off modifying your script to make it more easily testable by running it directly. You will save yourself a lot of time and heart ache

Having 0 knowledge of this script, but going on you're saying the only reason you can't test it directly is because it requires POST variables that are passed to it, I would suggest spoofing those:

```
//top of page
$_POST['field'] = 'test';
```

Debug it, then worry about cURL

Comment: Hmm seems fair. Well, I guess there's no other way then, although that will be a ton of POST variables to spoof :|  But thank you anyway :)